# How can I find the cosine similarity between rows of the same column(python pandas), and take the highest match which is not itself?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, cosine-similarity

I have a dataset of 2 columns( 1st column words(bigrams) and the second column is their count). I want to merge the counts of similar words and remove the similar words( 'client relation' and 'client relations' are similar, I want to add the count of 'client relations' to that of 'client relation' and remove 'client relations').

I have tried this with fuzzywuzzy, but it takes ungodly amount of time and the kernel crashes.

fuzzywuzzy code:

```
**#Create tuples of brand names, matched brand names, and the score score_sort = [(x,) + i
             for x in unique_words 
             for i in process.extract(x, unique_words,     scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)]
#Create a dataframe from the tuples similarity_sort = pd.DataFrame(score_sort, columns=['word_sort','match_sort','score_sort']) similarity_sort.head()

similarity_sort['sorted_words_sort'] = np.minimum(similarity_sort['word_sort'], similarity_sort['match_sort']) similarity_sort.head()

high_score_sort =  similarity_sort[(similarity_sort['score_sort'] >= 80) &
                (similarity_sort['word_sort'] !=  similarity_sort['match_sort']) &
                (similarity_sort['sorted_words_sort'] != similarity_sort['match_sort'])] high_score_sort = high_score_sort.drop('sorted_words_sort',axis=1).copy()**
```

I only need to keep matching words that are not itself.
The above code takes enormous amount of time and the kernel stops. Is there any solution similar to this using some other similarity measure like cosine distance which could be faster?
Any help would be great. Thanks.